# Fisheye view showing unaltered geometry

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

When using fisheye camera lens my view shows both the altered geometry and the original geometry.  Is there a way to only make the altered Geometry visible?

Answer (score 0):

Those are just you **overlays** by default Blender always displays the overlays even in rendered mode :
[image]
[image]

You can view your scene (almost) exactly as it renders by disabling overlays :

[image]
[image]

Let me hear if that helped you.